# Insert video into another video both of different formats in a time efficient way

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg, mp4

I have an assignment which requires that the code I write takes a large video(1 to 3 hrs) and a smaller video (10-60 seconds) and the smaller video is inserted at intervals of 30 minutes into the larger video. Note that the videos are not necessarily in the same format.

I tried to encode the large and the small video to a common format (mp4) and then split the large video based on time (while encoding it to mp4) and then concat all the videos in a predefined sequence (also while encoding to mp4). All these operations were carried out using FFMPEG.

Although this method worked, it too close to 20 hours to perform the whole operation on an Intel NUC (having an i5 processor and 8GB RAM)

Is there a faster way to do this without compromising on quality ?

Comment: There are likely two unnecessary encoding steps happening here. Why encode the large video? Encode the small video to match the properties of the large video and then concat in copy mode.

Comment: I need to automate the whole process. Any suggestions on how I can do that? Right now I've written a python script to do so

Comment: @Mulvya. This method worked out. Now the whole process completes in less than 2 minutes. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @SharathHuddar Since you found a solution you should add it as an answer to your question.